How to determine if hybridization takes place between orbitals in an ab initio calculation using Quantum ESPRESSO?
I'm using Quantum ESPRESSO to determine the electronic properties of systems. Now I want to confirm if hybridization takes place between orbitals. I have generated density of states and projected density of states files. But I'm not sure how to know if hybridized orbitals exist or not.
